# Firestore array-contains-any object based on one of two fields

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have following array in my document:
[image]

I have SizeFilterComponent which emits BaseFilter object on size select change. I can select multiple sizes.
This is method which handles logic:

```
selectionChange($event){
    let array = [];
    for(let el of $event){
      array.push({size: el})
    }
    let filter: BaseFilter = {
      field: 'sizes',
      symbol: FilterSymbol.arany,
      value: array
    } 
    this.filterChanged.emit(filter);
  }
```

But the problem is  that sizes have count field. This is field is number higher or equal zero.
I want to filter items that have sizes with count higher than 0. How can i do that?

When i change line to
`array.push({size: el, size: 10})` im getting item on the screenshot. But i want to get something like `array.push({size: el, size: >0})` (its just graphically, i know syntax is horrible)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but if your goal is to get any documents where any item in the array has a count > 0, then that is not possible. The reason is that `array-contains` and `array-contains-any` only work when you match the entire/exact item that you pass in, which isn't possible for your query.

I'd recommend either:

- Storing the counts in map fields, like `sizes.M.count`. While this is in general not recommended when you can't predict the number of items, it should be fine here since the number of sizes is finite and not very high.
- Adding a `isInStock` field to each array element, which you then update whenever you also update the `count` for that size.

I'd pick the first option, but there is a bit of personal preference involved in tat.

Comment: You mean `sizes: Map<string, string>[];`  where the key is the size and value is the count?